# how can i format flot chart Data

Tags: jquery, html, graph, flot

i am stuck on how to input a real-time int value from my data source and put into a flot chart !. my current problem is that i cant seems to figure how to change the x and y axis. The data or idea of how it would work is that i would have a source that provide a value every second all i need to do is to plot on to the graph.

[Here's is the link to the image of the graph look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgqYI.png)

Here is my code my problem is that how to change getRandomData() method into my data that feeds only one value every second.

example i have a data `var energy = 10;` So the chart suppose to stay 10 until a new value appear

Thanks sorry for any bad english

```
    $(function() {

        /*
         * Flot Interactive Chart
         * -----------------------
         */
        // We use an inline data source in the example, usually data would
        // be fetched from a server
        var data = [], totalPoints = 100;
        function getRandomData() {

            if (data.length > 0)
                data = data.slice(1);

            // Do a random walk
            while (data.length < totalPoints) {

                var prev = data.length > 0 ? data[data.length - 1] : 50,
                        y = prev + Math.random() * 10 - 5;

                data.push(y);
            }

            // Zip the generated y values with the x values
            var res = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
                res.push([i, data[i]]);
            }
            console.log(res);
            return res;
        }

        var interactive_plot = $.plot("#interactive", [getRandomData()], {
            grid: {
                borderColor: "#f3f3f3",
                borderWidth: 1,
                tickColor: "#f3f3f3"
            },
            series: {
                shadowSize: 0, // Drawing is faster without shadows
                color: "#3c8dbc"
            },
            lines: {
                fill: true, //Converts the line chart to area chart
                color: "#3c8dbc"
            },
            yaxis: {
                show: true
            },
            xaxis: {
                show: false
            }
        });

        var updateInterval = 500; //Fetch data ever x milliseconds
        var realtime = "on"; //If == to on then fetch data every x seconds. else stop fetching
        function update() {

            interactive_plot.setData([getRandomData()]);

            // Since the axes don't change, we don't need to call plot.setupGrid()
            interactive_plot.draw();
            if (realtime === "on")
                setTimeout(update, updateInterval);
        }

        //INITIALIZE REALTIME DATA FETCHING
        if (realtime === "on") {
            update();
        }
        //REALTIME TOGGLE
        $("#realtime .btn").click(function() {
            if ($(this).data("toggle") === "on") {
                realtime = "on";
            }
            else {
                realtime = "off";
            }
            update();
        });
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you asking how to change `getRandomData` to fetch your data instead?  Where is your data located?  In a file on the server?

Comment: @Mark its a json object that i retrieve from another file which i have declare on top of my code i have already pass it into a java variable now what i want to achieve is that how am i going to put in that variable value into the realtime graph

Comment: Can you update your question with how that JSON data looks in it's variable?  Do you want to plot it all at once or update the plot one point at a time until there's no data left?  Do you ever retrieve updated data from the server vka AJAX?

Comment: @Mark erm sorry mark for all this trouble erm it does not require to preload the value it can start to update once the variable got data 

i have already decode and put the value nicely in a variable 

like this 

var energy = 10;

so i need to update the graph every second based on the energy variable

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure I understand but I'll give it a go.

Store your energy variable in an accessible scope to the below function.  On some interval call this function and push energy variable onto your data and redraw the plot.  If you update energy variable elsewhere this function will use the new value.

```
function update() {
  var addedData = interactive_plot.getData()[0].data; // get current data
  addedData.push([addedData.length, energy]); // add energy value
  interactive_plot.setData([addedData]); // redraw chart
  interactive_plot.setupGrid();
  interactive_plot.draw();
  setTimeout(update, updateInterval);
}
```

Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ikBbnaOVpa2f6FOvPayH?p=preview).